# Products attributes in a category products for the frontend

Tags: frontend, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In our Prestashop [1.7.8], for a specific products category (to manage the different category, we have done 2 differents product.tpl file), we would like to display all products with their attributes something like that :

- apple : 1$ : add to cart
- tomato : 0.8kg : 1$ : add to cart
  1kg : 1.2$ : add to cart

With $product.attributes, we can have the 1st attribute but not all : is it a way to display all of them in the front ?

EDIT :
We done a module, but with the new version of Prestashop, this one doesn't work anymore /modules/delivery/controllers/front/Category.php  :

```
<?php
class DeliveryCategoryModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{    
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

....
```

I have an internal error 500 : Error: Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found.

EDIT 02 : Finally, I re-write my module and all works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done, but it's not just a few lines of code.
What you need is a “combination grid”. Check this module:
https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/product-page-combinations-table.html